# Ubiquitous Language and Custom types

Tags: domain-driven-design

Note that my question is referring to those attributes that even on their own already represent a *concept* ( ie on their own provide a *cohesive meaning* ). Thus such attribute needs no additional functional support and as such is *self-contained*.

I'm also well-aware that even with *self-contained* attributes the *custom types* may prove beneficial ( for example, they  give the ability to add new behavior later, when business requirements change ). Thus, my question focuses only on whether *custom types* for *self-contained* attributes really enrich Ubiquitous Language **UL**

a) I've read that in most cases, even simple, *self-contained* attributes should have custom, more descriptive types rather than *basic value types* ( *double, string* ... ),  because among other things, *descriptive types* add to the **UL**, while the use of *basic types* instead weakens the language.

I understand the importance of **UL**, but  how does having a *basic type* for a *self-contained* attribute weaken the language, since with *self-contained* attributes the name of the attribute already adequately describes the *concept* and thus contributes to the **UL** vocabulary?

For example, the term `person_age` already adequately explains the concept of *quantifying the number of years a person has*:

```
class Person
{
       string person_age;
}
```

so what could we possibly gain by also introducing the term `ThingAge` to the **UL**:

```
class person
{
      ThingAge person_age; 
}
```

thanks

Comment: The more fine grained you specify your types the more compile time verification you can get that you aren't misusing any types. That said, I wouldn't create a type in your particular case and really don't know what you're talking about at all through the course of this question.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: "the more compile time verification you can get that you aren't misusing any types." Your solution is of technical nature and has got nothing to do with DDD

Comment: That might be because I don't know anything about DDD, my comment is just that; a comment from my knowledge and experience and the fact that you talk about creating a class for `Age` which would generally be bad design. What quality it has in relation to DDD isn't something I can speak to, I can only speak to it's qualities in regards to writing and maintaining software. I didn't write an answer because I have no idea what you're talking about in here. My comment was technical in nature because this is a site for Programmers. Hi, I'm a Programmer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a system that considers ages of different "things", then having a `ThingAge` type could be useful. For example, an insurance software system considers the age of drivers and the age of vehicles (for automobile), the age of buildings (for home and commercial property). It might be useful to have further subtypes such as `DriverAge` for drivers, which has logic particular to drivers (such as related to being above/below regional minimum driving ages), and other types such as `HouseAge` that has logic related to regional heritage structure rules.  `EquipmentAge` might relate to mechanical/industrial equipment that might be relevant for underwriting.

Of course, in such a system you don't *need* to have `ThingAge`, `DriverAge`, `HouseAge`, `EquipmentAge` types; it's just *one* way to do it that may be legitimate in some systems. In others, it might not be a good way to do it.

If your system will *only* ever consider "people" as having an "age" attribute, then having a `ThingAge` type might not be very useful.

Comment: "It might be useful to have further subtypes such as DriverAge for drivers, which has logic particular to drivers" In that case we must create a subtype, since basic type doesn't contain a behavior required by age_of_driver attribute.

Comment: Would it be correct to assume that in most cases self-contained attributes should have custom types only when different things/objects all contain the same kind of attribute A ( for example, all objects contain an attribute representing the concept of age ), but in each of these things A is named differently ( House.HouseAge, Person.PersonAge etc )? In that case it may be beneficial to create a custom type for A, so regardless if team is talking about an age of a house or a person, the use of the term "ThingAge" will make it obvious they are referring to the same concept of age?

Comment: @EdvRusj: RE your first point: `ThingAge` could have some basic logic, such as the numeric age value must be greater or equal to `$MIN_AGE` and less than or equal to `$MAX_AGE` (assuming the system defines such a value).

Comment: Do you agree with my second point?

Comment: I generally think that custom types should only be created when they will actually have different functionality, or will be used in different ways (or there are clear future plans for them to be different/be used differently). Back to the insurance example: The system might want to distinguish different vehicle types: `Motorhomes` and `Cars`, but the age-related logic for them is the same, so they would both have an age attribute of the same type, `VehicleAge`.

Comment: I'm not arguing whether or not different vehicles types should have their age attribute of the same or different type ( it makes sense that if their age-related logic is the same, then their attribute should also be of the same type ). Instead I'm asking whether their age attribute should be of basic type (say int) or should it be of custom type ( say VehicleAge, which of course they could share if age-related logic is the same), even if int type already includes all the behavior age attribute will ever need?

Comment: @EdvRusj: Ok, that's a little more clear. For me, I'd say that if the system can be refactored so references to `ThingAge` could be replaced with `int` and everything else would work fine, then `int` probably should have been used in the first place. I'm generally not a fan of adding new types to a system , when they are *just* containers for another type with *no* extra logic.

Comment: So you disagree that for the purpose of enriching UL even the simplest ( ie self-contained ) attributes should have custom types ( even though basic type such as int would suffice )?